# With Javascript code how to detect if user is using my website using Telegram web app or uses regular browser?

Tags: javascript, telegram

How I can detect if user is using my web app using telegram web app. I need to show some information if he is.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the navigator.userAgent property, but this can be easily edited by the user to appear as something else.

```
function isUserOnTelegram(){
    return navigator.userAgent.includes('Telegram');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will try. How could this be edited ?

Answer (score 0):

Joshua's answer can work but it is not recommended since the user can easily bypass it.

The best way is to check if web sockets are available, sin some features are not available on telegram web app.

This is the code for it:

```
const supportsWebRTC = !!window.RTCPeerConnection;
if (supportsWebRTC) {
  // Likely a regular browser
} else {
  // May be Telegram web app
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, none of those work, I even used  

const isRegularBrowser = !!(window.navigator.mediaDevices && window.MediaStream);

but no luck

Comment: Well another option is to add a telegram parameter for example: https://coolweb.com/?telegram=true. Then check for the parameter but the use can easily remove it.

Comment: Thank you! Good solution.

Could you also help how I can check if user opened telegram web app with Telegram Desktop or with mobile ?

Comment: I don't know @Lara . There is no way to check

Answer (score 0):

As long as all Telegram Mini Apps applications must have [launch parameters](https://docs.telegram-mini-apps.com/platform/launch-parameters), you could check if they were specified.

So, if launch parameters are missing, it most likely means, that the application was launched in a regular browser. Here is the example using the [@tma.js/sdk](https://docs.telegram-mini-apps.com/packages/tma-js-sdk) package.

```js
import { isTMA } from '@tma.js/sdk';

console.log(isTMA());
```

Nevertheless, users are able to copy the launch parameters and use them in the regular browser.

Knowing, that all Mini Apps are launched in the Telegram environment, we can call some Telegram Mini Apps method and receive a response. In case, there is no response, it means, that it is surely regular browser. This flow seems more stable.

Here is the code:

```js
import { request } from '@tma.js/sdk';

let isTMA;

try {
  await request('web_app_request_theme', 'theme_changed', {
    timeout: 100,
  });
  isTMA = true;
} catch {
  isTMA = false;
}
```